# iOS/Android background audio streaming

Tags: cordova, background, streaming, mp3

I am considering using phonegap to target both ios and android. But before I start I need to know for sure if, and how, I can have background audio streaming.
I would have a url to a fixed length mp3 somewhere on the web, and I need to play this whether the app is open or in the background, and be able to keep track of when the mp3 ends.
Any notes, personal experience in this regard, links, etc. would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the answer for Android, but for iOS it is possible to enable background audio with a phonegap application. However, you'll need to modify the phonegap source in able to get this working, and also add a name/value pair to the info.plist file of your project. For full details, see [this post](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap).

Comment: Okay great. That's what I've been hearing. Now I just need to know for sure for Android (and if so, what versions of Android of course)